# Question regarding confusing outlet smart switch install

Tags: receptacle, installation, smart-switch

I've been recently trying to install 2 new smart switches in place of some older light switches, but I cant for the life of me figure this out.

Here is a picture I drew of the current wiring as I can see it in the box:
[image]

There are 2 plugs at the bottom of the stairs, these control 2 different sets of basement lights and are what I'm trying to replace.  There is also another switch at the top of the stairs that controls the set of lights closest to the stairs in the basement.

The smart switches I have are 2x 3-way and 1x 1-way.  My plan was to install the 2 way switches in place of the 2 switches in the basement and possibly use the other 1-way for our bedroom or somewhere else.

[image: New plugs]

I'm not quite sure how to wire this up and I think the additional plug upstairs might be confusing me as well.  I've tried multiple multiple configurations and thought I have identified the traveler plugs and the hot line appropriately using my electrical gear, but I feel there is a gap in my understanding that I'm hoping I can get a hand with.

Comment: Your situation is typical. Of course you want to choose where to put the smart switches, but 3-way and 4-way circuits give you no choice as to location. For each light, you will need to map out the wiring for ALL related switches, and then go from there and figure out which smart switches can go where.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question, as well as the other boxes in that circuit?

Comment: Thats a good idea - I will try to do this asap.